# Angularjs component is not updating the model for the view

Tags: angularjs

My component does not update `latlng` in view by the click event on the map. What's wrong?

```
class Controller {
  constructor() {
    this.latlng = [-25.363882,131.044922];
  }

  getpos(event){
    this.latlng = [event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng()];
    console.log(this.latlng);
  }
}

angular.module('app', ['ngMap']).component('myMap', {
  template: `
    <ng-map center="-25.363882,131.044922" zoom="4" on-click="$ctrl.getpos($event)">
      <marker position="{{$ctrl.latlng}}" title="Hello World!" on-dragend="$ctrl.getpos($event)" 
        animation="Animation.BOUNCE" animation="DROP" draggable="true">
      </marker>
    </ng-map>
    {{$ctrl.latlng}}`,
  controller: Controller
})
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0wevtLo6/)

Comment: Yes you are right. I lose the context of my component because the method is called through the on-click attribute (not ng-click) that has a ngmap context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `getpos` event handler is bound, the context of the function execution is getting modified and `this` is no longer refers to controller, instead it refers to map object.

You could consider the following options on that matter:

One option would be to pass `$ctrl` property to `getpos` function:

```
on-click="$ctrl.getpos($ctrl)"
```

and then `latlng` property could be modified like this:

```
getpos(event,ctrl){
  ctrl.latlng = [event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng()];
};
```

Demo

```js
class Controller {
  constructor() {
    this.latlng = [-25.363882,131.044922];
  }
  
  getpos(event,ctrl){
     ctrl.latlng = [event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng()];
     console.log(ctrl.latlng);
  };
}

angular.module('app', ['ngMap']).component('myMap', {
    template: `
    <ng-map center="-25.363882,131.044922" zoom="4" on-click="$ctrl.getpos($ctrl)">
      <marker position="{{$ctrl.latlng}}" title="Hello World!" on-dragend="$ctrl.getpos($ctrl)" 
        animation="Animation.BOUNCE" animation="DROP" draggable="true"></marker>
    </ng-map>
    {{$ctrl.latlng}}`,
    controller: Controller
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <my-map></my-map>
</div>
```

Another option would be to introduce a function which keeps the context of controller , for example:

```
class Controller {
    constructor() {

        var self = this; 
        this.bind = function () {
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
            var event = args.shift();
            var fn = args.shift();
            fn.apply(self, [event].concat(this,args));
        };
    }
}
```

Then with binding:

```
on-click="$ctrl.bind($ctrl.getpos)"
```

`latlng` property could be modified via `this`:

```
getpos(event) {
    this.latlng = [event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng()];
};
```

Demo

```js
class Controller {
    constructor() {
        this.latlng = [-25.363882, 131.044922];

        var self = this; 
        this.bind = function () {
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
            var event = args.shift();
            var fn = args.shift();
            fn.apply(self, [event].concat(this,args));
        };
    }



    getpos(event) {
        this.latlng = [event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng()];
        console.log(this.latlng);
    };
}

angular.module('app', ['ngMap']).component('myMap', {
    template: `
      <ng-map center="-25.363882,131.044922" zoom="4" on-click="$ctrl.bind($ctrl.getpos)">
        <marker position="{{$ctrl.latlng}}" title="Hello World!" on-dragend="$ctrl.bind($ctrl.getpos)" 
          animation="Animation.BOUNCE" animation="DROP" draggable="true"></marker>
      </ng-map>
      {{$ctrl.latlng}}`,
    controller: Controller
})
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>




<div ng-app="app">
    <my-map></my-map>
</div>
```